# no visible @interface for declares the selector ‘set Range With Minimum:and Maximum:’

Tags: ios, objective-c, shinobi

I want to run xcode project from [here](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/play-charts-gallery). I get error message:

> No visible @interface for declares the selector ‘set Range With Minimum:and Maximum:’ in SPUGalleryManagedChartViewController.m file.

How to fix it?

```
 if (self.ranges) {
    for (int i=0; i<self.chart.allAxes.count && i<self.ranges.count; i++) {
      if (self.ranges[i]) {
        SChartRange *range = (SChartRange *)self.ranges[i];
        [self.chart.allAxes[i] setRangeWithMinimum:range.minimum andMaximum:range.maximum]; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this a compilation error?

Comment: @hasan83 yes it is.

Comment: Is this a code you added? or its the project code?

Comment: @hasan83 I didn't change anything. Its the project code.

Comment: does this code exist in SPUGalleryManagedChartViewController.m file?

Comment: I cant find that file in the project!

Comment: @hasan83 If you didnt clone repository via desktop version6 you should download these files in description below and place them like in instruction.

Comment: @hasan83 If you download the zip rather than cloning the project, you'll also have to download the submodule zips:

Download play-charts-utils and extract its contents into the ChartsGallery/ShinobiPlayChartsUtils directory.
Download play-utils and extract its contents into the ChartsGallery/ShinobiPlayChartsUtils/ShinobiPlayChartsUtils/ShinobiPlayUtils directory.

Comment: I am doing that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** I am a developer at ShinobiControls.

We have updated the [play gallery](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/play-charts-gallery) repository to be compatible with the latest version of ShinobiCharts (2.9.0).

The issue you were seeing was caused by us removing a previously deprecated method "setRangeWithMin:Max:". This was replaced with the "setRange:" method where you provide the chart with a range object rather than it's min and max values.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hello.Thanks you for fix it. But I have another problem with trial license key) I paste my trial license key in viewdidload of ChartsGalleryViewController.m like in instruction. But it still asking with the error message: No ShinobiControls license key given - please set chart.licenseKey = @"<your trial license key>"
(lldb)